# Laravel 5 password reset through sendinblue

Tags: laravel, sendinblue

I have a laravel 5 app and need to send a reset password link through a service sendinblue. How can I change the core functionality to use sendinblue in PasswordBroker.php?

```
public function emailResetLink(
    CanResetPasswordContract $user,
    $token,
    Closure $callback = null
) {
    $mailin = new Mailin(
        'https://api.sendinblue.com/v2.0',
        '0TYSSJBSKERNDKW'
    );

    $view = $this->emailView;

    return $this->mailer->send(
        $view, 
        compact('token', 'user'),
        function($m) use ($user, $token, $callback) 
        {
            $m->to($user->getEmailForPasswordReset());

            if ( ! is_null($callback))
            {
                call_user_func($callback, $m, $user, $token);
            }
        });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to add Sendinblue as a mail driver? This github repo can help (https://github.com/agence-webup/laravel-sendinblue)

Here all your emails will be sent by Sendinblue and you will send as a regular mail in Laravel (https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/mail)

If is just for this, you can change the driver just for this kind of mail, i think that you can change the driver on runtime like this

```
Config::set('mail.driver', 'driver_name');
(new Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider(app()))->register();
```

Also, you can try to listen to 'mailer.sending' event that is fired just before sending mail messages, but this is not a good approach.

Comment: This do not work as I am using Laravel 5.0 and this is for 5.1

Comment: this gives me composer error - Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages

Comment: Maybe update to Laravel 5.1 will be easier, the first driver that i sent to you is really good and looks more easy to work. I don't belive that will be hard to update 5.0 to 5.1